# mongodb remove fails on "invalid object id"

Tags: shell, mongodb, guid

I'm trying to delete documents using MongoDB shell, but for some reason it keeps failing on "invalid object id: length"

**query**:

```
db.collections.remove( { _id : ObjectId("FF125DF6-E977-404A-9E8C-600CDAFEFF53" )} );
```

**error**:

> Mon Dec 24 03:11:15 Assertion: 10448:invalid object id: length
>   0x6073f1 0x5d1aa9 0x5ac3f1 0x5b84f4 0x6aa5ac 0x6aaec8 0x69e4e7
>   0x6aa13f 0x668e46 0x668ec2 0x66a2ce 0x5cbcc4 0x4a44a6 0x4a67e6
>   0x7f2554e2fcdd 0x49f669   mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21)
>   [0x6073f1]  mongo(_ZN5mongo11msgassertedEiPKc+0x99) [0x5d1aa9] 
>   mongo() [0x5ac3f1] 
>   mongo(_ZN5mongo21object_id_constructorEP9JSContextP8JSObjectjPlS4_+0x2b4)
>   [0x5b84f4]  mongo(js_Invoke+0x40c) [0x6aa5ac] 
>   mongo(js_InvokeConstructor+0x108) [0x6aaec8] 
>   mongo(js_Interpret+0x37c7) [0x69e4e7]  mongo(js_Execute+0x36f)
>   [0x6aa13f]  mongo(JS_EvaluateUCScriptForPrincipals+0x66) [0x668e46] 
>   mongo(JS_EvaluateUCScript+0x22) [0x668ec2] 
>   mongo(JS_EvaluateScript+0x6e) [0x66a2ce] 
>   mongo(_ZN5mongo7SMScope4execERKNS_10StringDataERKSsbbbi+0x144)
>   [0x5cbcc4]  mongo(_Z5_mainiPPc+0x2156) [0x4a44a6]  mongo(main+0x26)
>   [0x4a67e6]  /lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd) [0x7f2554e2fcdd] 
>   mongo(__gxx_personality_v0+0x2a1) [0x49f669] Mon Dec 24 03:11:15
>   Error: invalid object id: length (shell):1

I tried running

```
db.repairDatabase();
```

but nothing is changed.
from checking around i see that its a known issue,is there a workaround for this?

**EDIT**

here is the document as it is in the db:

> {
>
> "_id": "FF125DF6-E977-404A-9E8C-600CDAFEFF53",
>
> "data": {
>
> ```
>    "files": [
>    ],
>
>    "categories": [
>   ],
>
>    "trash": [
>    ]
>  }
> ```
>
> }

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`ObjectId("FF125DF6-E977-404A-9E8C-600CDAFEFF53")` is invalid. [ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/object-id/) is 12-byte BSON type and could not have '-' inside. Check the source where you get this id.

Comment: I got this id by navigating the db using rockmongo, what can i do to get the right one?

Comment: I think it is a String id, not a ObjectId. Try {_id:".........."} in the remove operation.

Comment: I tried db.collections.remove( { _id : "FF125DF6-E977-404A-9E8C-600CDAFEFF53" } ) but the document was not deleted

Comment: So there is no document matches this id. Use mongodb console to check that.